# DataGridView getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form that has dataGridView and transfers its value to textboxes but I keep getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when I clicked any of the columns.

These codes are working fine if only rows are clicked.

```
private void dataGridProd_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridProd.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridProd.Columns)
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

            txBName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txBPrice.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        btnAdd.Enabled = true;
        prodQuanUpDown.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Any type of response is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: On the productName and productPrice

Comment: How many items in the row.Cells array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't see why you need a `foreach` loop here and per your post if you are getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` then it has to be because of the below two lines. do you really have those many columns for the rows? You can check the `Count` property on the `Cells` collection saying `row.Cells.Count`

```
txBName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
txBPrice.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the product product name really in the 2nd column of the table if it is in the first column it should be `row.Cells[0].Value.toString();`

`row.Cells[1].Value.toString();`<--this is for the 2nd column thats your price then if it is in the 2nd column

Hope this answer helps!